# Know device orientation when orientation is locked

Tags: javascript, angular, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, mobile-chrome

I have a webApp that need to be displayed only in portrait-primary orientation. In order to do this I lock the rotation in the manifest.

The problem is that when I take photos in the webApp I need to know the orientation of the device even if it's blocked. I tried to do it with [devideOrientationApi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation). But I am not able to know the correct orientation of my device.

Any help would be great. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I have the exact same scenario.  Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

You can check for the window's inner width and height like below,

```
this.isPortrait = window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth;
```

Comment: When you lock the orientation in the manifest the width and height of the window is static even if you rotate the mobile into diferent orientations.